# Delegate Method when Deleting App

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

is there a delegate method in iOS when an application is about to be remove?
I'm trying to send to server that the device will no longer receive notification.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. There is no delegate method which fires when the app is being deleted.

Comment: pretty sad to know it