# Uninstall ReactNative App - Clean User Data

Tags: react-native

I want to clean the User AuthData Saved in Mobile upon uninstall. AuthData is saved using AsyncStorage. 
Is there any mechanism by which I can detect App Uninstall in ReactNative

Comment: The AsyncStorage saved by your application should be automatically cleared upon app uninstall, at least on iOS. I am not sure what the behavior is on Android.

Comment: Are you sure about that @jevakallio? My understanding (and I could be totally wrong) is that AsyncStorage data is available across apps, which is why best practice is to namespace your keys with something like `@AppName:key`. Here's an excerpt I pulled from the book *Learning React Native*, "The storage key used by AsyncStorage can be any string; it’s customary to use the format @AppName:key, like so:"

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't seem possible, especially if your app is not running at the time they uninstall. However, there seems to be a couple approaches you can take, but neither is perfect.

1. If your app is running, you can listen for `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` (see [Detect iOS application about to delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911361/detect-ios-application-about-to-delete))
2. Use the push notification feedback service (see [Delegate Method when Deleting App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911976/delegate-method-when-deleting-app/7912045#7912045))

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this solution (swift code): https://stackoverflow.com/a/40732677/3151214

Variable [userDefaults (`NSUserDefaults`)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults) can be accessed through [`Settings` in React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/settings), so javascript implemetation can be looked like:

```
import { Platform, Settings } from 'react-native';

function getAuthData() {
    let isStoreNeedCleaning = false;

    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        if (!Settings.get('hasRunBefore')) {
            Settings.set({ hasRunBefore: true });
            isStoreNeedCleaning = true;
        }
    }

    if (isStoreNeedCleaning) {
        // Clean up your store
    } else {
        // Load auth data from store
    }
}
```