# How disable iOS autobackup app data?

Tags: ios, react-native, backup, react-native-ios

I have a application in react-native and when I remove and reinstall it application the data is restored. I have resolution on Android using

```
android:allowBackup="false"
```

in AndroidManifest.xml, but the same problem happens in iOS. Does anyone have a similar solution for iOS?

Comment: Don't do that.  Don't destroy the user's data.

Comment: I need to remove the login information that persists in the application because the app currently login automatically when it is reinstalled, but the client does not want this behavior.

Comment: Agree with SLaks, you really shouldn't be doing that. There are ways to structure your code to work around this but it really depends on how you've persisted your data, etc. This is also possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820946/uninstall-reactnative-app-clean-user-data). I can't flag it though since there's no accepted or upvoted answer.

Comment: When using login with OAuth question is probably about remembered cookies. You want to delete them, right?

Comment: I am using login with firebase and saving the token in asyncstorage. When I reinstall the application, the asyncstorage data returns and the application automatically logs in, appearing on a screen that it should only have access after login.