# Remove all UILocalNotifications after application uninstalled by the user

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I want to delete all the `UILocalNotification`s when a user uninstalls/deletes the application.

Which delegates will be called when application is uninstalled? How can I remove all  `UILocalNotification`s after deleting application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911361/detect-ios-application-about-to-delete

Comment: which notification there is Push notification, UILocalNotification, or UINotification Center

Comment: iOS will delete the notifications when your app is deleted. You don't need to (and can't) do anything when your app is deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's no such delegates. The App itself can not detect its deletion.
2. You don't need to remove local notifications by yourself. The system deletes them automatically while deleting the App.

Comment: Even deleting application also I am getting notification

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Device did not delete the notification even after i delete the application ,After deleting the application also notification get fire