# delete all events from calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

i am creating an iOS application, which get dates from the server and add them events to the calendar: 
I'm adding them with this code :

```
- (void)addReminderWithTitle:(NSString *)title date:(NSString *)date {
    NSString *dateString = date;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter  = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [dateFromString dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*30];    
   EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted) {
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
        event.title = title;
        event.startDate = dateFromString;
            //[NSDate date]; //today
        event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
        event.calendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
        NSError *err = nil;
        [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
        }}];
        }
```

and I need a function, that will delete all the events on a specific action from the user.
any help?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321921/how-to-delete-all-the-events-of-my-app-calendar-when-app-is-deleted-from-device?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an array of all events from calendar and filter them in an array by some identifier, date or title so that you can get your own added events.

```
// Create the predicate from the event store's instance method
NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:oneDayAgo endDate:oneYearFromNow calendars:nil];

// Fetch all events that match the predicate
NSArray *events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
```

Then loop over the array of `events` and delete them like this

```
EKEventStore* store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
   EKEvent* event2 = [store eventWithIdentifier:[arrayofCalIDs objectAtIndex:i]];
if (event2 != nil) {  
  NSError* error = nil;
  [store removeEvent:event2 span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
}
```

Comment: from where did you get  "arrayofCalIDs" ?

Comment: After this line `NSArray *events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];` you'd have array of `EKEvent` and if you'll run a loop on `events` array, you can get each event. PS: forget  `arrayofCalIDs `, thats my code

Comment: i did this :           for (int i = 0 ; i<events.count;i++){
    EKEventStore* store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
  [self.arrayofCalIDs addObject:title];
     EKEvent* event2 = [store eventWithIdentifier:[self.arrayofCalIDs objectAtIndex:i]];
        
    if (event2 != nil) {
        NSError* error = nil;
        [store removeEvent:event2 span:EKSpanFutureEvents error:&error];
    }
but the event2 is returning nil, so nothing is been removed