# Remove username/password stored using KeychainItemWrapper iphone-sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, security, ios4

I stored the username password in iphone application using KeychainItemWrapper class. but this info exists after removed the application from device. So can any one suggest how i remove this info from device when application removed from device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete iphone keychain items when application uninstall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747404/delete-iphone-keychain-items-when-application-uninstall)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "callback" or any other way to know when the application is removed from the device. The record will stay there until the device is wiped or reset to factory defaults.