# Salesforce MobileSDK iOS persisting OAuth token after uninstall

Tags: ios, oauth, salesforce

We are using the Salesforce Mobile SDK for iOS to create a native iPhone app that uses OAuth to log in to a SFDC org.

After the app is uninstalled and re-installed the application currently logs in successfully with the OAuth token provided prior to the uninstall.

E.g. Timeline

- Download and install first time
- Provide login credentials
- Log in successfully
- Uninstall app
- Cleared browsing history, cookies and data from Safari
- Download and install app again
- Try to log in
- Log in happens without the need to supply log in credentials again

Question: Where is the SDK storing the token, can we delete it or null it on uninstall of the app? Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The information will be stored on the device's keychain [see](http://forcedotcom.github.com/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/Documentation/SalesforceOAuth/Classes/SFOAuthCredentials.html) and so will persist if you do not tell it to be removed when you uninstall the application. A good discussion of this can be found on a [different thread here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747404/delete-iphone-keychain-items-when-application-uninstall)

Paul