# NSHTTPCookieStorage loosing cookies if app starts before phone has been unlocked at least once after a reboot

Tags: ios, iphone, cookies, nsurlrequest, nsurlsession

**Problem**

As the title says, I'm currently experiencing an issue where the `NSHTTPCookieStorage` is loosing the cookies for our app when it's initialised in background before the phone has been unlocked at least once after a reboot.

Once the cookies are lost, they can't be recovered in any way, forcing the user to re login to retrieve a new set of cookies and recover a session.

If app activity is registered for the first time AFTER the user has unlocked her/his phone, then everything works like a charm.

**Context:**

- This issue happened to us using `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLSession` as well
  as using ASIHTTP and AFNetworking with automatic cookie handling, so
  we came to the conclusion its affecting the whole `NSHTTPCookieStorage`
  class.
- Our app has SLC (Significant Location Change monitoring) so its
  triggered in background automatically.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Make a demo app that performs a network call ("Lets call it CALL
   A"), to authenticate to a server, getting some cookies in response
   to that.
2. Perform a second call (Lets call it "CALL B") that requires this
   cookies to be sent in order to work. If everything goes well, cookies
   should be automatically managed and sent to the server accordingly.
3. Make your demo app be able to execute some background stuff, for
   example enable SLC monitoring. In the execution of this background
   behaviour perform "CALL B" again (If it's inside a background task
   or not doesn't really matter for the test purpose)
4. Reboot your phone and DON'T unlock it.
5. Wait until the SLC, or the background behaviour you chose is
   triggered and CALL B is done.

   TIP: You can disable and enable Airplane mode to force an SLC trigger on the device.

   Problem: If in that time a significant location change is triggered, the app looses all the cookies forever, without any chance of recovering them in any way.

Any help or idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saving and storing the cookie in user defaults between app restarts?

Comment: No, we aren't. We are not handling cookies manually. All Cookie management is done automatically by the NSURLRequest class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that iOS is having [this same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269116/nsuserdefaults-loosing-its-keys-values-when-phone-is-rebooted-but-not-unlocked) but with cookies stored on NSHTTPCookieStorage.

I've already created a radar so feel free to add more so this issue is pushed up a bit in the queue. Radar number is 16237165.

In the meanwhile, you can perform the following workarounds:

1. Handle cookies manually (aka not rely on iOS automatically
   managing cookies and storing them in the `NSHTTPCookieStorage`
   class). But **DON'T** use `NSUSerDefaults` because its having the
   same issue.
2. **Prevent all network activity before phone has been unlocked at least once**. This is the option we took and we did the following:

   - Create a file in disk with the `NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication` permission.
   - Before making any network call, check if the app is able to read that file. If it is, it means phone was unlocked at least once, so you are good to do the call without loosing cookies.

Here is a code sample:

`static BOOL phoneIsUnlocked = NO;`

```
//If this var is true, then avoid re checking if file has permissions (Cause if it was granted permissions once, it will have access now)
if(phoneIsUnlocked) return phoneIsUnlocked;

//If phone has never been unlocked, prevent all networking stuff just to make sure cookies are not lost due to an ios7 bug.
//Creates a file with NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication permissions. If the app is able to read it, it means the phone was unlocked at least once after a reboot.

//Get the file path
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"a.secure"];

//create file if it doesn't exist
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileName])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileName
                                            contents:[@"secure" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                          attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication
                                                                                 forKey:NSFileProtectionKey]];

NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:fileName];
phoneIsUnlocked = file != nil;     //If file is not nil, the phone has been unlocked
[file closeFile];
```

Answer (score 0):

From your described behaviour it seems that the protection on the underlying file store used by `NSHTTPCookieStorage` has been set ["Complete until first login"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW11).

As you can't change where and how `NSHTTPCookieStorage` stores your data you have a couple of choices:

1. Use a different method for storing your cookies
2. Check the [`protectedDataAvailable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/protectedDataAvailable) property of `UIApplication` and defer your updates until the device is unlocked.  You can register for the [`UIApplicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable) notification to be advised when the device is unlocked.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We took a very similar path to what you suggested. We tested the ```protectedDataAvailable``` stuff but it has one big problem, that is, it will also return ```NO``` if the phone is locked but has been unlocked previously at some point. If phone has been unlocked at least once, cookies won't be lost no matter if the phone is locked or not at the moment of the network call, so this solution actually prevents us from doing any behaviour if the phone is locked, which is far more restrictive that what we want(We need that back behaviour when phone is locked for the ap to work)

Comment: Then you may need to create another file with the same level of protection and then test the readability of that file to confirm whether your cookies are available. *Edit* - I just saw that this was the technique suggested in the other answer

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for the feedback anyways. Nice help