# Sign Out of Firebase in Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, compiler-errors, logout

I want to do sign out from my application after i signing in with firebase, and i tried this code in my application but it not working.

```
print("clickSignOut")
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
       } catch {
         print("can't signOut")strong text
       }
      print(Auth.auth().currentUser ?? "no user")
```

Comment: The Firebase auth session is stored in the users keychain which is why it looks like they are still authenticated with the print statement. You need to manually remove that keychain data using the technique in the linked question. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301815/firebase-ios-swift-firauth-auth-signout-not-signing-out-current-user#answer-40412452) for some code suggestions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This always works for me:

```swift
do {
    try Auth.auth().signOut()
} catch let error {
    print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
}
```

If this isn't working for you, provide us with some more context. What do you mean by "it's not working"? If you use this code provided, it will tell what error you're encountering.

Comment: i tried it, its not working as well

Comment: How is it not working though? Is the error getting called or is this `try` line not even being attempted? Can you set some breakpoints to understand the flow better?

Comment: no its not getting an error but its not signOut when i clicked on the item bar button

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint within your button's `@IBAction` function to ensure that the code is even being called?

Comment: Okay i will, i will do it

Comment: Thank you so much its working now

Comment: Isn’t this a duplicate of the code in the question?

Comment: Basically yeah, but I added error handling for the try statement. It seems, however, that his code wasn't even being run

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps:

```
try! Auth.auth().signOut()
```

Comment: i tried it, its not working as well

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: okay of course.

Comment: @IBAction func signOutButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
        }

Comment: Not this. Is the whole code on GitHub?

Comment: No, i will upload it on the GitHub.

Comment: Did you upload it?

Comment: No i didn't because it's working now, and much appreciated you helped me to figure out a solution.

Comment: You are welcome! An upvote would help. :D