# Android, Firebase Auth, user session still exists when user deletes and reinstall app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my first launching activity there is lines of code that checks if user is logged in by Firebase:

```
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MenuActivity.class));
                finish();
    }
    else 
    {

                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
    }
```

If user is logged in I open **MenuActivity** if not then **LoginActivity**

In my **LoginActivity** I authorize with `signInWithCredential`.

I have found one interesting problem.

When user deletes application then reinstalls it from Google Play and launches it **user is still logged in and opens MenuActivity**

I have found similar question [but with iOS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893418/firebase-deleting-and-reinstalling-app-does-not-un-authenticate-a-user).

Is it feature of Firebase?
How it is possible to invalidate user session when user deletes application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase support answered me and yes Firebase tries to keep some data even if appliaction is deleted.

In order to clear data when deleteing, I needed to disable backuping in my applications manifest in `application`:

```
android:allowBackup="false"
android:fullBackupContent="false"
```