# How does FirebaseUI/Firebase auth authenticate a mobile number without OTP after 1st attempt?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseUI and Firebase authentication to authenticate users using phone number. During testing I saw that when I first used my phone number I was sent an OTP but after that I have uninstalled and installed my app many times but now it does not ask for OTP and just verifies the phone number and logs me in. So I would like to know how is firebaseUI/auth doing it. Is it linking android device Id to a phone number  or saving it in shared preferences which is saved on cloud?

If this is not the case how is firebase UI/auth doing it ? . My app only has location permission.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase tries to keep some data in your device even if it was deleted. It is called making backups.

[I think this is related to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042337/android-firebase-auth-user-session-still-exists-when-user-deletes-and-reinstal)

You just need to add these lines in your manifest file inside `application` tag:

```
android:allowBackup="false"
android:fullBackupContent="false"
```

Comment: I think it uses SharedPreferences and sometime before I read sharedpreferences data is saved on the cloud and could be retrieved after uninstallation.

Comment: Maybe yes, but I have written my problem to firebase support, they answered to my question like that.

Comment: I would like to know how exactly are they doing it.