# Firebase auth persistents across delete and install

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I noticed that when I delete my app and install it again the user is still logged in. I found that the web sdk has the ability to control auth persistence: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence. How can I change the persistence with the iOS SDK.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893418/firebase-deleting-and-reinstalling-app-does-not-un-authenticate-a-user

Comment: @JenPerson This could be a dupe, but I want to be able to control the persistence instead of work around the issue.

Comment: Still having this issue 8 months later -- both iOS and Android for me

Comment: @Kai I doubt they'd change anything, I'd do the workaround from Dari in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39162617/359532