# Why FirebaseAuth currentUser() is kept after uninstall the app?

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to get the login state of the user in Flutter, whenever I run my application for the first time (**Only when I uninstall and reinstall the app**) following code return a user.

I already tried to get the user from `whenComplete` and `then` both return
the same.

```
 FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;    
 FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
 return user;
```

returned user is a platform user from my android device, and if I reload my app after install user will be removed.

Edit:

1. I already tried all the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48660787/979653
2. I removed all the users from my Firebase
3. My app showing a user id which is not in my Firebase.

Funny thing is minimizing the app removes the unknown user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Authentication returning specific user when app is uninstalled and Installed again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660300/firebase-authentication-returning-specific-user-when-app-is-uninstalled-and-inst)

Comment: @Christilyn No luck, tried that and I also deleted all my users from firebase and it still returns uid when I check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because data will persist anyways offline in some cases regardless of the app being deleted or not, and thus, your previous Firebase user.

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169618/an-android-app-remembers-its-data-after-uninstall-and-reinstall) answer:

> It's because Android 6 has automatic backup. You need to tune
>   android:allowBackup and android:fullBackupContent in your manifest
>    tag if you don't want your data backed up or if you want
>   to include or exclude some resources. It's not a bug.

So basically, add `android:allowBackup="false"` and `android:fullBackupContent="false"` in manifest.xml and you should be fine.

Comment: And what about iOS devices? I am suffering from that same problem but on iOS

Comment: @WaqasYounis On iOS [it's related to Keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893418/firebase-deleting-and-reinstalling-app-does-not-un-authenticate-a-user).