# Firebase Auth saved after uninstall. How can I delete it?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've recently discovered that Firebase Auth saves itself on the device even after my app is uninstalled. I can't figure out how to REMOVE this old Auth info.

I don't want a user to still be signed in after uninstalling and reinstalling the app. If for no other reason than my own testing of what I expect to be "clean installs" on the same device.

I understand there is no easy way to capture an uninstall event, so I want to clear out any potential old Auth info on the first launch.

So I added code (which seems to work fine) to check if this is the first launch:

```
Boolean firstRun = prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true);
if (firstRun) {
    // delete everything an old user could have left behind
    // ==> This is where I need help <==
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).apply();
} else {
    // move along, not the first launch
}
```

I've tried (unsuccessfully):

```
FirebaseAuth authData = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();  
authData.signOut();
```

These calls also seem to be the advice in this related question for iOS, but I haven't been able to apply its wisdom:
[Firebase - Deleting and reinstalling app does not un-authenticate a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893418/firebase-deleting-and-reinstalling-app-does-not-un-authenticate-a-user?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Even after calling `signOut()` the app keeps logging me in under the old account!

My "logout" button uses `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` and works. **Is there something odd (possessed?) about this "old" Auth instance that is being saved after an uninstall that it just won't die**?

Specifically when I uninstall and then install/run from Android Studio:

1. at first authData and currentUser both are not null
2. I call the above code, trying to get rid of this old user
3. 3 millisecond later (immediately after I call that
   code) they are still NOT NULL.
4. Another 2 milliseconds, currentUser IS NULL (yay?)
5. Another 71 milliseconds... still null (so far so good)
6. Just under a second later... I'M SIGNED IN AS THE OLD USER?! How is this possible?

In the Firebase Console under Authentication, this account is shown as last signed in 6 days ago. So it's not somehow getting re-signed-in.

**Does anyone know how to remove FirebaseAuth data from a device? I don't want to "delete" the user account, just remove all traces of it from this device.**

Oddly enough, the account I keep getting unwillfully logged in under isn't even the last account that logged into my app on this device. And this was never a problem in the past (hence my not even knowing that Firebase saved Auth after uninstall). So it looks like Auth info isn't **always** saved after uninstall... but when it happens it's impossible to remove?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

Add `android:allowBackup="false"` in your `<application>` in manifest:

From the docs:

> [`android:allowBackup`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#allowbackup)
>
> Whether to allow the application to participate in the backup and restore infrastructure. If this attribute is set to false, no backup or restore of the application will ever be performed, even by a full-system backup that would otherwise cause all application data to be saved via adb. The default value of this attribute is true.

Comment: Interesting. I'm a little worried taking away this backup could negatively effect more users than the issue I'm having with auto login after uninstalling and reinstalling...

Comment: Would setting allowBackup to false mean that when a user selects to install all their old apps on a new device that mine would not be included?

Comment: This quote from developer.android seems a bit confusing. I'm not sure what a `full-system backup` is and I'm also not sure what impacts can it cause to set allowBackup to true. I was searching, but after few attempts, could not find anything. However, the answer solved my problem and if the same happened with @KaitlynHanrahan, the answer should be accept as the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Try also FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().delete

Answer (score 0):

Firebase stores auth info in shared preference with file names starting with "com.google.firebase.auth.api.". Therefor if you delete these files as part of your log off flow it would help the purpose.

```
public void clearFirebaseAuthInfo(Context ctx)
    {
        File dir = new File(ctx.getFilesDir().getParent() + "/shared_prefs/");
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
        {
            if(children[i].contains("com.google.firebase.auth.api."))
            {
                new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
            }
        }
    }
```