# Auth state still persisting in react-native(iOS) even after uninstalling and reinstalling! Using Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

This is due to Keychain in iOS which saves the Auth state even after uninstalling the app.

How can I delete the keychain Auth state in react-native or prevent this from happening?

I’m using react-native-Firebase v6

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `firebase.signOut()` use the `signOut` method

Comment: Yes but how to fire that when the app is being uninstalled?? What if a user doesn’t manually sign out and just uninstalls the app?

Comment: You need to write native code I guess, AFAIK react native does not provide any API

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase - Deleting and reinstalling app does not un-authenticate a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893418/firebase-deleting-and-reinstalling-app-does-not-un-authenticate-a-user)

Comment: @Johan yes, but I don’t have experience with Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

hope this help someone! 
i found this [response](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/694#issuecomment-352435164) in github and just add

```
[FIRApp configure];
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 if (![defaults boolForKey:@"notFirstRun"]) {
 [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notFirstRun"];
 [defaults synchronize];
 [[FIRAuth auth] signOut:NULL];
}
```

in my `AppDelegate.m` and my issue fixed.