# Flutter iOS not wiping firebase user data

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm currently implementing Firebase within my Flutter application, the code that I have to detect if the user is signed in or not is the following:

`bool get isCurrentUserLoggedIn => FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null;`

However, when I remove the application, the current user instance from `FirebaseAuth` is still there.

The steps that I'm doing to delete the application in my iPhone SE 2nd generation is the following:

- Hold press the application
- Click on **Remove App*
- Click on **Delete App*

Note: I'm seeing **Remove ""** in the title of the alert that I'm getting from the system. That indicates me that something is wrong.

Comment: Firestore Authentication stores the credentials in the iOS keychain, which is not cleared when the app is uninstalled. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893418/firebase-deleting-and-reinstalling-app-does-not-un-authenticate-a-user and the other questions I linked.