# After new Login app show old user data from firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to display current user data from Firebase, and it works totally fine, but when I logout and login with a new email ID, the app also shows previous user data instead of new user login data.

My signIn function in Signin page

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  //when user is login then save their userid and after use this for fetching current user data
  //this help in StudentData.dart page
  var userId;
  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  //for Validation
  final _key = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  //for geeting input and store email & password
  var email = "";
  var password = "";

  //for Loading Indicator
  bool isLodaing = false;

  //for login
  Future userLogin() async {
    //check internet is on or not
    final ip = context.read<InternetProvider>();
    await ip.checkInternetConnection();

    //for checking Internet
    if (ip.hasInternet == false) {
      openSnackbar(context, "Check your internet connection", Colors.red);
    } else {
      try {
        UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

        //when user loged in that time save user id that help after for fetch data in StudentData.dart page
        // widget.userId = userCredential.user!.uid;
        setState(() {
          widget.userId = userCredential.user!.uid;
          print("User id is : " + userCredential.user!.uid);
        });
        print("Widget User id is : " + widget.userId);

        //show succuful log-in meesage
        openSnackbar(
            context, "Log-in Successfull", Color.fromARGB(255, 70, 213, 92));

        //after login go to profile Page
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstPage()));
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        //for no user Found
        if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
          //for stoping the loading indicator when user get this error
          Future.delayed(
            Duration(seconds: 0),
            () {
              setState(() {
                isLodaing = false;
              });
            },
          );

          //show Snack Bar when this error occur
          openSnackbar(context, "No User Found for this e-mail", Colors.red);
        }

        //for Wrong Password
        else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
          //for stoping the loading indicator when user get this error
          Future.delayed(
            Duration(seconds: 0),
            () {
              setState(() {
                isLodaing = false;
              });
            },
          );

          //show Snack Bar when this error occur
          openSnackbar(context, "Wrong Password", Colors.red);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: HexColor("#F9B684"),
        body: GestureDetector(
          //when user tap on screen tahat time keybord disumissed
          //this is use for avoiding overflow screen
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),

          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
                // this is main Column
                children: [
                  //Heading
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80, left: 20),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 75, top: 13),
                    height: 80,
                    width: 265,
                    // color: Colors.white,
                    child: Text(
                      'Login',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 43,
                        color: HexColor("#2D0C03"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  //for image
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    height: 200,
                    width: 265,
                    // color: Colors.white,
                    child: Image.asset("assets/images/login.gif",
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),

                  const SizedBox(height: 17),

                  //for TextFileds
                  Form(
                    key: _key,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 23.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          //for E-mail Text Filed
                          TextFormField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,

                            //for move to cursor next Text automatically
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,

                            //for autofil e-mail
                            autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
                            controller: emailController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.email,
                                color: HexColor("#002C00"),
                              ),
                              hintText: "e-mail",
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(33)),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: HexColor("#002C00")),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
                              ),
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
                              ),
                            ),

                            //for validation
                            validator: (value) =>
                                value != null && !EmailValidator.validate(value)
                                    ? 'Enter valid e-mail'
                                    : null,
                          ),

                          const SizedBox(height: 10),

                          //for Password Text Filed
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: passwordController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.password,
                                color: HexColor("#002C00"),
                              ),
                              hintText: "password",
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(33)),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: HexColor("#002C00")),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
                              ),
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
                              ),
                            ),

                            //for validation
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return "Please enter password";
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                          ),

                          //for forget Password
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                            // color: Colors.yellow,
                            height: 35,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                            child: TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                //goto Forget Password Screen
                                nextScreen(context, ForgetPassword_Page());
                              },
                              child: const Text(
                                "Forgot Password",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Gotham',
                                    color: Color(0xff1778F2),
                                    fontSize: 14.5),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                          const SizedBox(height: 9),

                          //for sign-in Button
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 50,
                            width: 170,
                            child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                primary: HexColor("#98504B"),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                ),
                              ),

                              //for loading indicator and Text
                              icon: isLodaing
                                  ? const SizedBox()
                                  : const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, size: 24),

                              label: isLodaing
                                  ? Row(
                                      children: [
                                        //for circular indicator
                                        Container(
                                          margin:
                                              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 7),
                                          height: 25,
                                          width: 25,
                                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                            color: HexColor("#2D0C03"),
                                            strokeWidth: 3.5,
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        ),

                                        //for text
                                        Container(
                                          margin:
                                              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 7),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Please Wait..",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontFamily: 'Gotham',
                                                color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  : const Text(
                                      'Sign-in',
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'Gotham', fontSize: 22),
                                    ),

                              //here we call method name signup for storing data in firebase
                              onPressed: () async {
                                //for validation
                                if (_key.currentState!.validate()) {
                                  isLodaing = true;
                                  setState(() {
                                    //when user enter email & password then store those email and passwors in variable which intialize in top
                                    email = emailController.text;
                                    password = passwordController.text;
                                  });

                                  //for Showing Loaing Indicator
                                  Future.delayed(
                                    Duration(seconds: 3),
                                    () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        isLodaing = true;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  );

                                  //for user login
                                  userLogin();
                                }

                                //after run above line of code this Stop the Loading Indicator
                                Future.delayed(
                                  Duration(seconds: 3),
                                  () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      isLodaing = false;
                                    });
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),

                          //for sign-up opotion below login button
                          Container(
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text('Does Not Have Account? '),
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    nextScreen(context, RegistrationPage());
                                  },
                                  child: const Text(
                                    "Sign-UP",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      letterSpacing: 0.2,
                                      fontFamily: "Ubuntu",
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      color: Color(0xff1778F2),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

UserData controller Class:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:gtu_all_in_one/Pages/LoginPage.dart';

//this class help for fetching current user info from firebase
class StudentDataController extends GetxController {
  final firebaseInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  //after data fetch insert data in this
  Map StudentProfileData = {
    'name': '',
    'EnrollmentNo': '',
    'Email': '',
    'Branch&Sem': ''
  };

  //create loginpage instance for getting current user userid , using this we fetch the data
  LoginPage authController = LoginPage();

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    getStudentProfileData();
  }

  Future<void> getStudentProfileData() async {
    // print("user id ${authController.userId}");
    try {
      var response = await firebaseInstance
          .collection('users')
          .where('user_Id', isEqualTo: authController.userId)
          .get();
      // response.docs.forEach((result) {
      //   print(result.data());
      // });
      if (response.docs.length > 0) {
        StudentProfileData['name'] = response.docs[0]['name'];
        StudentProfileData['EnrollmentNo'] = response.docs[0]['EnrollmentNo'];
        StudentProfileData['Email'] = response.docs[0]['Email'];
        StudentProfileData['Branch&Sem'] = response.docs[0]['Branch&Sem'];
      }
      print(StudentProfileData);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
}
```

And profile Page where i trying to display current user data:

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  //when user come in profile page after login that time this create instance of StudentDataController and go to StudentData Page
  final StudentDataController controller = Get.put(StudentDataController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // for logout button
    final sp = context.watch<SignInProvider>();

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 300),

              Text("Name : ${controller.StudentProfileData['name']} "),
              Text(
                  "Enrollment No : ${controller.StudentProfileData['EnrollmentNo']} "),
              Text("Email  : ${controller.StudentProfileData['Email']} "),
              Text(
                  " Branch& Sem : ${controller.StudentProfileData['Branch&Sem']} "),

              SizedBox(height: 10),

              SizedBox(height: 10),

              //for Opening QR Code Scanner
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                width: 250,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: HexColor("#48EDC5"),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
                    ),
                  ),

                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      //for text
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 13),
                        child: Text(
                          "Mark Attendance",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Gotham',
                              color: HexColor("#002C00"),
                              fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),

                      //for Icone
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.qr_code_scanner,
                          size: 22,
                          color: HexColor("#002C00"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                  //goto QR Code Scanner Page
                  onPressed: () {
                    nextScreen(context, QRCodeScanner());
                  },
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(height: 10),

              //for LogOut Button
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                width: 150,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: HexColor("#48EDC5"),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
                    ),
                  ),

                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      //for text
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 13),
                        child: Text(
                          "log Out",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Gotham',
                              color: HexColor("#002C00"),
                              fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),

                      //for Icone
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                          size: 22,
                          color: HexColor("#002C00"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                  //goto SignUp Page
                  onPressed: () {
                    sp.userSignOut();
                    nextScreenReplace(context, FirstPage());
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You shared *a lot* of code with a lot of moving parts in there, many of them not related to the specific problem that you're asking about. While you may always get lucky and somebody may spot the problem and answer, chances of that go up drastically if you take the time to isolate the problem in a [minimal, complete repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I experienced what I think is the same issue. It occurs because firebase is storing the user identifier in KeyStore and Keychain (cloud backed up for identifying across devices). I fixed with an this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69621552/12132021