# Function that detects an app uninstall/reinstall

Tags: swift, swift3

Been [looking around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747404/delete-keychain-items-when-an-app-is-uninstalled) to find a way to detect when an app is uninstalling/reinstalling. The thing is, I do not use `NSUserDefaults`, I use [SwiftKeychainWrapper](https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper).

I need to clear that user's keychain when app uninstalls.

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` seems to call when app loads so no use there. Is there a way to detect a reinstall? I need to call this:

```
return KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey: "myKey") // only when/if app is unsinstalled/reinstalling
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you're using Keychain because you need to store sensitive information? If so then you could just store a boolean in `UserDefaults` and check if that exists. For example:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let freshInstall = !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "alreadyInstalled")
    if freshInstall {
        // delete your item from keychain
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "alreadyInstalled")
    }

    return true
}
```

This way you still have the security of the Keychain, but the behaviour of UserDefaults on uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: Thanks. There seem to be an issue with SwiftKeychainWrapper; your method do called at the correct time so hence I make this answer correct. Thanks.

Comment: This code doesn't provide an information that contains a reinstallation or uninstallation of an app. It just tells you that I'm a new app.

Comment: @ayteq Completely true, however unfortunately there is no way to invoke code when your app is deleted on non-jailbroken devices, this approach achieves the same goal in a roundabout way however, and the OP did specify in his question that checking upon re-install was fine for his scenario.

Answer (score 1):

for others searching for the way to clear the Keychain in the "// delete your item" part of the answer.....

Swift 3

```
let _ = KeychainWrapper.standard.removeAllKeys()
```