# remove keychain data after app installation

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, keychain

I have a requirement to store app credentials securely (keychain recommended) and remove the data after user install the application. But in iOS 10.3 device I could see the data still there even after uninstallation and re-installation. Is there any way to remove keychain data after uninstallation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, the keychain data will persist until the device is erased.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete keychain items when an app is uninstalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747404/delete-keychain-items-when-an-app-is-uninstalled)

Comment: I think user defaults  get removed when you uninstall an application, but in debug mode sometimes it not get erased somehow, really, 
but in distribution or apostore release they get removed.